# C# Regex Port Validation 49152 to 65535

Tags: c#

After reading about ports and suggested ports I discovered that to comply with Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) recommendations for private ports you should only use ports from 49152 to 65535. As such I have attempted a regex pattern to check that the user has entered a port within that range. I have pieced this together with a great headache I had to read a lot of tutorials to get this far regex patters are really not human friendly. Basically I am looking for someone with more knowledge than me to verify that it is correct. My testing seems to indicate it but maybe I am missing something I just wanted to make sure.

```
string pattern = @"^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d\d|6[0-4]\d{3}|5\d{4}|49[2-9]\d\d|491[6-9]\d|4915[2-9])$";
```

Regards!

Comment: Seriously? Regex to check integer bounds?

Comment: I think this is a typical  case  you should NOT use a regex

Comment: I agree with mensi; why can't you just use < and > to test?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a string and an integer and how they are represented in memory and why so.

Comment: It never occured to me to be honest. I was so involved with using regex to find valid ip ranges that i kinda just used when i moved onto the port

Comment: Nonetheless, +1 for the effort. The regex seems correct.

Comment: @Douglas thanks for validation, While everyone else maybe correct in pointing out it may be totally incorrect to use regex here which I have now taken on board its nice to know the regex appears to be correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why using regular expression?

```
string input = "51204";
int portNumber;
if (int.TryParse(input, out portNumber) 
    && portNumber >= 49152 
    && portNumber <= 65535)
{
    // Valid value...
}
```

Comment: I can see the logic in this. It just never occurred to me to do so, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        int port;
        bool InRange = Int32.TryParse(StrPort, out port) && port >= 49152 && port <= 65535;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) and then validate the resulting integer to bounds instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer to your question, but you can just use:

```
int port = Convert.ToInt32(input);
if (port >= 49152 && port <= 65535) {
  //port is valid
}
```